# Banded facepulls vs DB rear delt flys

Tags: injury, injury-prevention, shoulders, resistancetraining, rehabilitation

A while back I had a very stubborn case of tricep tendonitis/osis.

I rehabbed it with slow-tempo tricep exercises as prescribed by my PT, but it came back a few years later. Another PT said it was because my scapular wasn't functioning correctly.

The exercises he gave me were really ineffective, but I found that doing a load of facepulls fixed my tricep problem (or at least it meant I could continue rehabbing my tricep effectively again).

But before facepulls, I was doing tonnes of rear delt flys... I would have thought these would help with my triceps but they didn't really have any effect.

So my question is — don't rear delt flys work the same muscles as facepulls? What do facepulls do that rear delt flys don't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as how it relates to your tricep tendonitis, it's hard to give any specific indication for which exercise is better or worse.

What I will say is that the facepull is quite different from the rear delt fly (RDF) because with the facepull, you are working on external rotation of the shoulder, and not just the rear delt.

The RDF does one thing, and does it quite well; it works the muscles engaged in pulling your elbows back into a rear flexion. But the facepull does another thing, which is to maybe begin somewhat similar to the RDF, but then turns your arm outward. This is the movement where, if you cock your hand back as if you're going to throw a punch, but instead you sort of just strafe your fist past your ear. That's the external rotation. And it turns out that strengthening the shoulder rotators are crucial to a healthy and pain-free shoulder.

Again, how this affects your tricep tendonitis is unclear to me. But the differences between the RDF and facepull are non-negligible.

And to be clear, I'm not saying one is better. These are two distinct exercises, and you should do both. Not either/or.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good.

What confuses me is that I was also doing external rotation exercises along with the rear delt flys, but my elbow problem persisted. It's as if there is just something magical about facepulls that seems to fix it.

I was also doing a lot of serratus anterior exercises to help with my elbow problem, but I have a feeling it may have resulted in a rounded shoulders posture... which perhaps the facepulls help to counteract.

Comment: ...sadly this all seems to be too complex of a problem for any PT to figure out themselves, but I at least seem to be on top of it now anyway (I think!)

Comment: the PT that said your scapular wasn't functioning correctly I hope gave you some therapy or suggestions. Without knowing exactly the issue, if it is your scapula, you should focus on rehab for that along with mobility. doing cuban presses, facepulls, cable external rotations, etc.. along with mobility and stretches on days off might help if your scapula is pulling your triceps muscle tight. I'm no expert but tendonitis can be difficult to see what the problem is. The PT approach is to throw everything at the wall and see what sticks or helps. PT is a long journey, that changes exercises,

Comment: also talk to your PT if what they prescribed isn't working. This is part of the therapy is to evolve. If you feel better, ask them for recommendations first. if you find something that really helps, use that. It seems like external rotation seems to help. make that a huge priority and do exercises every other day along with stretches, and continue being gentle on your triceps(stay with pulldowns focusing on slow eccentrics rather than concentric, no lying extension or overhead  as they put a lot of unnecessary tension on the muscle.)

Comment: @AceCabbie thanks for the advice – I did actually tell the PT that his scapular exercises didn't appear to be working, he didnt have any other suggestions and said he'd refer me to a doctor (I wasn't keen on that idea though). I saw a bunch of other PTs but had little luck with them either

Comment: @AceCabbie many PTs seemed really focussed on my rotator cuff, but I've found that to have very little effect on my tricep tendonitis... I've found the most effective exercises to be various serratus anterior exercises, aswell as banded facepulls. I've been doing a lot of those this week and my elbow is feeling great, I'm hoping I can just carry on like this

Comment: @AceCabbie also my original PT did also say to avoid any overhead extensions, so I left them out for years – but recently I re-introduced them and actually felt pretty good. I should have just started doing them again a lot sooner